# Hyperledger Fabric Import identity in InMemoryWallet

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm trying to import identities of already enrolled users in InMemoryWallet. The main idea is to import users from external source when application needs it (like DB which stores all necessary information like certificates and private keys for each user) to avoid storing files in FS. And load `admin` identity when my application started. But have no luck with this.

```
// Here I'm using data from wallet files which was created after enroll of admin user
const cert = '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----certificatestring-----END CERTIFICATE-----'
const pk = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----privatekeystring-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'
const adminName = 'admin'

adminIdentity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', cert, pk);
wallet = new InMemoryWallet()

await wallet.import(adminName, adminIdentity)

const adminExists = await wallet.exists(adminName);
console.log('adminExists', adminExists) --> Exists!!!
await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: adminName, discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });
ca = gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();

// Trying to create User
const userId = 'someId'
const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'org1.department1', enrollmentID: userId, role: 'client' }, adminIdentity);
const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: userId, enrollmentSecret: secret });
const userIdentity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
await wallet.import(userId, userIdentity);
```

UPD: While executing I'm getting this error: 
`(node:85462) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authentication failure"}]]`

But when I'm doing the same from `FileSystemWallet` everything working as expected....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in certificate and private key format. The should be used 'as is'.
With all generated line breaks.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICAjCCAaigAwIBAgIUBrQKwHNcJLbF52MaYWh29/9UJRgwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw\nc...;
...LSdWpObOxeh\r\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\r\n;"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line here

```
wallet.import(adminName, adminIdentity)
```

it's an async method so you should do

```
await wallet.import(adminName, adminIdentity)
```

Comment: Thanx, you are right, but it's not properly login anyway `(node:85436) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authentication failure"}]]
` Getting this error( Will change main question.

Comment: You should check the logs of your CA it might give you more info as to why there was an authorisation failure